# How to use fork() to create a child process out of a child?

Tags: c, fork, response, pid

I want create a son(1) with fork() and this son needs to create another son(2).

son (1) and father needs to wait for their son's end gives a info. I want all of them to `printf` their PID.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

  int pid; //i know thats not good

  if((pid = fork ()) == 0) { //this isnt good either
    printf ("SON %d\n",getpid());

  } else {
    // sleep(1) not necessary
    printf ("Thats the Father\n");
    printf ("PID of my Son PID %d\n",pid);
  }
}
```

Found several infos to create multiple children out of 1 father but I don't know, how to create a new child out of a child.

Comment: processes are gender neutral.  `fork` creates a "child", not a "son".

Answer (score 1):

> Found several infos to create multiple childs out of 1 father but i dont know, how to create a new child out of a child.

It's exactly like how you create the first child process. You need to [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) again in the child process to create another process. Use [`wait(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) to wait for the child processes.

Consider the example (with no error checking):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(void){

pid_t pid;

if((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    printf ("Child process: %d\n", (int)getpid());
    pid_t pid2;

    if ((pid2 = fork()) == 0) {
        printf("Child's child process: %d\n", (int)getpid());
    } else {
        int st2;
        wait(&st2);
    }
} else {
    printf ("Parent process: %d\n", (int)getpid());
    int st;
    wait(&st);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great response. Got it know.

my actual code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

int pid;
int pid2;
int st;
int st2;

if((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    printf ("Kind: %d\n",getpid());

    if ((pid2 = fork()) == 0) {
        printf("Kindes Kind process: %d\n",getpid());
    } else {
                wait(&st2);

    }
} else {
    printf("Ich warte auf meinen Sohn\n"); //WAITING FOR MY SON
    wait(&st);
    printf("mein Sohn ist fertig\n"); // MY SON IS RDY
        printf ("Vater process: %d\n", getpid());
    printf("Vater: Status = %d\n",st); //MY STATUS AS A FATHER
}

return 0;
}
```

My outcome:

```
Ich warte auf meinen Sohn //waiting for my son
Kind: 2175 //pid children
Kindes Kind process: 2176 // childrens child pid
mein Sohn ist fertig //my son finished
Vater process: 2174 //father pid
Vater: Status = 0 //father status
```

My only problem is, that the PID of the first child prints out first. 
I want the child to wait for his own child and the prints out his own pid.

Like:

```
waiting for my Son(2)
pidchild2
my son2 finished
status
waiting for my son
pidchild1
my son1 finished
father pid
status
```

edit:

got it, i think

just had to printf beyond the wait2. was obvious

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

int pid;
int pid2;
int st;
int st2;

if((pid = fork()) == 0) {


    if ((pid2 = fork()) == 0) {
        printf("Kindes Kind process: %d\n",getpid());
    } else {
  printf("Ich warte auf meinen Sohn1\n");
                wait(&st2);
  printf("mein Sohn ist fertig2\n"); // MY SON IS RDY
  printf ("Kind: %d\n",getpid());
  printf("Sohn1: Status = %d\n",st2); //MY STATUS AS A FATHER

    }
} else {
    printf("Ich warte auf meinen Sohn\n"); //WAITING FOR MY SON
    wait(&st);
    printf("mein Sohn ist fertig\n"); // MY SON IS RDY
        printf ("Vater process: %d\n", getpid());
    printf("Vater: Status = %d\n",st); //MY STATUS AS A FATHER
}

return 0;
}
```